# Implementing zoom on UIScrollView

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, uiscrollview, uiimageview

I have inserted the delagates and proper code for the zoom function to work on the UIScrollView. However when I run the code, I get a "nil" return on the minimum or maximum zoom value. I dont understand how to bypass this. Any suggestions?

```
import UIKit
import MapKit
import MessageUI

class ViewController: UIViewController, UIScrollViewDelegate {

    @IBOutlet var scrollView: UIScrollView!
    @IBOutlet var tylenol: UIImageView!

    let backgroundImageView = UIImageView()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        setBackground()

        self.scrollView.minimumZoomScale = 1.0
        self.scrollView.maximumZoomScale = 6.0
    }

   func viewForZooming(in scrollView: UIScrollView) -> UIView? {
        return tylenol
    }


    func setBackground() {
        view.addSubview(backgroundImageView)
        backgroundImageView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        backgroundImageView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.topAnchor).isActive = true
        backgroundImageView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.bottomAnchor).isActive = true
        backgroundImageView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.leadingAnchor).isActive = true
        backgroundImageView.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.trailingAnchor).isActive = true

        backgroundImageView.image = UIImage(named: "background")
        view.sendSubviewToBack(backgroundImageView)
    }
```

Comment: Your code above specifically disables zooming as the minimum and maximum zoom levels are set to 1.0. Coffee needed?

Comment: Even when moving the value up it still states "Unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value"

Comment: You definitely have the IBOutlet connected in your storyboard and to the correct class?

Comment: The scene is linked to the ViewController. Scroll view is placed on the scene and the IBOutlet is referenced in ViewController as "scrollView." The image view is placed inside the scroll view and referenced in ViewController as tylenol.

Comment: Does it crash when it the viewdidload method is called and you try to set the  minimumZoomScale?

Comment: The app crashes before it even launches to the main screen. I changed the minimum zoom to 1.5 and 2.0 with the same complications.

Comment: Either unlink your iboutlets in your storyboard and redo the connections (they aren't connected properly whatever you might believe), or replace them with optionals. The error is because you are declaring the scrollview and Tylenol as non optionals (!) instead of (?) and when the view controller loads it expects them to exist and be connected.

Comment: Try replacing `@IBOutlet var scrollView: UIScrollView!` and `@IBOutlet var tylenol: UIImageView!` with `@IBOutlet var scrollView: UIScrollView?` and `@IBOutlet var tylenol: UIImageView?` respectively and where you set the minimum and maximum zoom `self.scrollView?.min....` : This will stop the crash but they still won't be connected in your storyboard, and so you won't be able to do anything with them.

Comment: Whilst that did work, the scroll view fails to zoom in. I honestly have no clue why...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The crash is caused by trying to unwrap one or both of your outlets which are declared as non-optional. These haven't been connected properly in the storyboard.

```
@IBOutlet var scrollView: UIScrollView!
@IBOutlet var tylenol: UIImageView!
```

Whilst unrelated to your problem, these should be declared as follows to avoid a retain cycle:

```
@IBOutlet weak var scrollView: UIScrollView!
@IBOutlet weak var tylenol: UIImageView!
```

In your storyboard, ensure these are all set:

[image: Check your view controller is of the correct class]
[image: check scrollview connections]
[image: check Tylenol connection]

Comment: Also make sure that Tylenol is in fact a subview of your scrollview. If you click and drag it over the scrollview, the scrollview will get highlighted.

Comment: This is my setup. The images are in the links.
https://ibb.co/WxJnMqB
https://ibb.co/b6PzS26
https://ibb.co/DbY12Gb

Comment: You've changed your @IBOutlets back to what I've put in my answer? i.e. with an `!` and not a `?`? That change along with the code you've posted should work. If it crashes then they aren't connected properly and you need to remove the connections and redo them.

Comment: ...Compare your scrollview screenshot to mine. You haven't set the delegate lol. You can do that in your viewDidLoad by calling `self.scrollView.delegate = self` or you can connect it in your storyboard. Either way, that's your issue.

Comment: When I redid the outlets, it reversed to the ! I did what you said and it worked perfectly! Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

You should set `minimumZoomScale` and `maximumZoomScale` with a value larger than `1.0`.